# Mongoose recusce delete records from db

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My MongoDB folders collection look like this:

[image]

Can I using moongose and have only id:55(Folder 1) remove from db all children? (Folder 2,Folder 3,Folder 4,Folder 5,Folder 6) and Folder 1 too, or get id 10(Folder 3) and  remove Folder 3,Folder 4,Folder 5?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In pure mongo it wouldn't be possible to do it automatically but if you're using mongoose you can make use of `post('remove')` hook.

```
folderSchema.post('remove', function(removedFolder) {
    folderModel.find({ parent: removedFolder.id }, function(err, subfolders) {
        subfolders.forEach(function(subfolder) {
            subfolder.remove();
        })
    })
});
```

Keep in mind, that hook will fire only after calling `.remove()` method on mongoose object. This is why in hook above we need to fetch all subfolders and remove each of them individually, instead just calling:

```
folderModel.remove({ parent: removedFolder.id })
```

You can read more about mongoose hooks here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html